# Building a circuit which adds 2 signed numbers

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, binary, karnaugh-map

I am developing circuitry to add 2 numbers with  sign.They have the form:

$$b_{1}:(sign)|(absoluteval)$$

I realised that the calculation of the sign of the addition of such 2 binary numbers must be exclusive from the calculation of the absolute value:There is the sign of  the 1 number , the sign of the other number and a carry which carries information on which number is bigger and is calculated from the summation process.

[image]

Now I was wondering if you could help me with the calculation of the carry out of 1 bit of the number.The game goes as follows:if the numbers have the same sign perform addition so the carry out will be the same with the carry out of a full adder.However if the numbers dont have the same sign , then addition changes so the carry out coming from the basic block of addition is different than the carry out of a normal full adder.The carry is calculated from (bit of negative number+carry in-bit of positive number).So have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Sign-magnitude notation is "inconvenient" for addition and subtraction. It might be easier to convert the numbers to 2's complement, add them, and then convert the result back to sign-magnitude.

Comment: Signed magnitude is also inconvenient in that it allows for \$\pm 0\$. So there's a question about whether or not you ever want to produce \$-0\$ as an output of the operation and, if so, an explanation about why so. Do you have a research or study paper that completely specifies the addition operation and status?